# PhoneGap iOS app fails to start on device only -- config.xml parse error

Tags: cordova

Running my app on the simulator works great. Trying to run the app on a device through XCode installs the app, shows the launch image, then fails with `NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'config.xml parse error line 43 col 23'`

line 43 is 
`<gap:platform name="ios" />`

When I remove that line it gives the same error with the same line number (pointing to the next line of the file).  This indicates to me the error is before line 43.  I have inserted random lines in the config file and verified that the line count changes, so this is the correct config.xml file.

I re-ordered some of the tags (i.e. feature tag, and name) but no difference.
I have completely removed the `platforms/ios` folder and have rebuilt on my local machine.

Here's the entire XCode output

```
2014-03-06 16:16:51.896 GetGrounded[299:907] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-03-06 16:16:51.922 GetGrounded[299:907] *** Assertion failure in -[CDVConfigParser parser:parseErrorOccurred:], /Users/anthonyelliott/Documents/code/simplicitymaximized/get-grounded/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVConfigParser.m:85
2014-03-06 16:16:51.927 GetGrounded[299:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'config.xml parse error line 43 col 23'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x311a32a3 0x38e2397f 0x311a315d 0x31a78ab7 0xab701 0x31abfa13 0x39120c5b 0x39133dcb     0x39139817 0x3913b0cd 0x3913aced 0x31abf937 0x31abf8e1 0x31abfb35 0x31abfbcb 0x9d895 0x9cd77     0x9ce3b 0xafff5 0x9cf99 0xb009d 0xaf97b 0x3300bad9 0x3300b663 0x3300384b 0x32fabc39 0x32fab6cd     0x32fab11b 0x34c9d5a3 0x34c9d1d3 0x31178173 0x31178117 0x31176f99 0x310e9ebd 0x310e9d49     0x33002485 0x32fff301 0xaf5b7 0xaf578)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

And here's my complete config.xml file.  Everything looks good to me, anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.simplicitymaximized.getgrounded" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
<name>GetGrounded</name>
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
<preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
<preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
<preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0" />
<preference name="PageLength" value="0" />
<preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page" />
<preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated" />
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<feature name="LocalStorage">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
</feature>
<access origin="*" />
<preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="false" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<gap:platform name="ios" />
<gap:platform name="android" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by generating a new phonegap project and copying over the new config.xml to my project (and then changed the name and id).  Not sure what exactly was wrong with my file, but it works now.

Comment: I think you were missing the `xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" ` part of the widget tag.

Comment: adding xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"  in the widget tag, will solve the error. thanks @QuickFix